# passing parameter to select statement from url

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database with a table which has two columns, lets say aa_id and bb_id - each of the the columns is a foreign key relating to another table and both columns are making a composite key for this particular table. there are several rows containing either the same aa_id and different bb_id or the same bb_id and different aa_id.
using pdo I want to extract the rows of the same - let's say - aa_id and I want to do this passing the parameter value in url. so the result of the select statement should be several rows and they should be saved as - for example - an array. 
I have tried to do this with following code:

```
$sql = sprintf("select aa_id, bb_id from a_table where aa_id=:aa_id");
$res = $db->query($sql);

$rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key . " - " . $value . "</br>";
}
```

And it give no result.

I does work if I state the value of aa_id in the query like this

```
$sql = sprintf("select aa_id, bb_id from a_table where aa_id=191919");
```

, but it extracts no data if I put the value in url.

I am not really sure what to search for in the web because I don't know what's the notation called (if it is). If somebody could tell me what may be wrong with the code or give me directions to what I should look for in the web among tutorials or documentation I will be grateful. Perhaps somebody could recommend a good source of knowledge about mysql, php and pdo... Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not binding the values, are you?

Comment: http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: your sprintf is correct? http://php.net/sprintf i missing value. sprintf(format, value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yeah, `:indicator` doesn't just automatically load in `$_GET['indicator']`, you need to manually bind it.

Assuming the URL ends with, `?aa_id=191919`, your code might look something like this:

```
$sql = "select aa_id, bb_id from a_table where aa_id=:aa_id";
$res = $db->prepare($sql);

$res->bindValue(':aa_id', $_GET['aa_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 

$res->execute();

$rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: yes, it helped. thank you. what I had to do was to use a while-loop instead of foreach. it looked like this: while($rows=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)... and it excluded the line $rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). when I used foreach it only gave me one row (the first with the parameter), while-loop with the line I mentioned as excluded gave me the rows without the first one... only the version I wroted above worked. thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I should have caught that other thing too. Yep, you've gotta use while for row fetching.